# better way of writing for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I saw following for loop recently somewhere in article

```
var i, len, arr = [1, 2, 3];
for (i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
     // do stuff here
}
```

But I dont know why above loop should be used than the following

```
var i, arr = [1, 2, 3];
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     // do stuff here
}
```

Which is better and which one is more preferred to use?

Comment: The first is caching the array length. http://www.erichynds.com/blog/javascript-length-property-is-a-stored-value

Comment: Though we can not conclude anything with a three element array, [here](http://jsperf.com/length-variable-in-for-loop) is the performance comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference seems to be caching the arrays length, which in some cases saves some time as the length property doesn't have to be looked up on every iteration, but for an array with three indices it doesn't make any difference, and it probably wouldn't make much of a difference if the array had a million indices either, so do whatever you'd like.

Personally I always tend to iterate in reverse if possible, and avoid issues with cached length, live nodeLists and other things.

```
for (var i=arr.length; i--;) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be an optimization (or a micro optimization as others already mentioned).

One case where it's a must imo is when iterating over *live* DOM `NodeList`s.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName( 'div' );
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ) {
    // Neverending loop
    document.body.appendChild( document.createElement( 'div' ) );
}
```

When working with *live* collections a developer need to take precautions. Either by caching the length or by taking a snapshot of the collection and than iterate over the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the function `length` in your loop the function is called each time. Is better to declare a new variable and save the array length inside :

```
for(var j=0, arrayLength=array.length; j < arrayLength ;j++){}
```